# Simple Text Retrieval with iOS Simulator

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, httprequest

This is my first attempt at retrieving network data with a PHP script in iOS. I have a simple php script at [www.mobilenicity.com/test.php](http://www.mobilenicity.com/test.php) that simply echoes the word 'success'. My intention is to be able to retrieve this text and output it through an NSLog command.

For now, I'm using the iOS simulator, and I'm not sure if that creates any issues that I need to deal with. I am able to use the simulator to access web pages via Safari, so I know that there is connectivity there.

I've been staring at this for quite a while but I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Here is what I have. The NSLog output is "download didn't work". I know from using another `NSLog` that I am failing in the `didFailWithError` method. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get at the output from NSNotificationCenter.

Can anyone see the problem? Thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *s = @"http://wwww.mobilenicity.com/test.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:s];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    MyDownloader *d = [[MyDownloader alloc] initWithRequest:req];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(finished:)
                                                 name:@"connectionFinished"
                                               object:d];
    [d.connection start];
}

- (void) finished: (NSNotification *) n
{
    MyDownloader *d = [n object];
    NSData *data = nil;
    if ([n userInfo]) {
        NSLog(@"download didn't work");
    } else {
        data = d.receivedData;
        NSLog(@"%@", data);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name: @"connectionFinished"
                                                  object:d];
}
```

MyDownloader.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyDownloader : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSURLConnection *connection;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSData *receivedData;

- (id) initWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *) req;
- (void) cancel;
@end
```

MyDownloader.m

```
#import "MyDownloader.h"

@interface MyDownloader()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSURLConnection *connection;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSURLRequest *request;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableData *mutableReceivedData;
@end

@implementation MyDownloader

- (NSData *) receivedData
{
    return [self.mutableReceivedData copy];
}

- (id) initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)req
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self->_request = [req copy];
        self->_connection =
            [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
        self->_mutableReceivedData = [NSMutableData new];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.mutableReceivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
     [self.mutableReceivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"connectionFinished"
     object:self userInfo:@{@"error":error}];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"connectionFinished" object:self];
}

- (void) cancel
{
    // cancel download in progress, replace connection, start over
    [self.connection cancel];
    self->_connection =
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self->_request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
}

@end
```

Comment: What exactly *is* happening?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll add that to my post. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug the problem I logged the error in `-connection:didFailWithError:` like so:

```
NSLog(@"-connection:didFailWithError: %@", error.localizedDescription);
```

The error message I got:

```
A server with the specified hostname could not be found.
```

Which led me to double check your host name "http://wwww.mobilenicity.com/test.php" and realize you have `wwww` instead of `www` :)

Fix that and convert the downloaded data to a string like Sunny shah showed you and you'll be A-OK!

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't see that. I've spent hours trying to figure this out. At least I'm much more familiar with downloading and NSNotificationCenter. (And much more embarrassed.) Thank you!

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip on logging the connection error. I was trying to figure out how to get this information from the notification center.

Comment: Happy I could help. Has happened to me on more than one occasion!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *text=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:d.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

Comment: Thanks. Still getting the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Change viewDidLoad method to following

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSStringEncoding encoding;
    NSString *urlContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wwww.mobilenicity.com/test.php"] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&err];
    if(urlContents)
   {
       NSLog(@"urlContents %@", urlContents);
   } else {
       NSLog(@"err %@",err);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sure. Unfortunately it crashed the program due to a NULL cString.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Didn't know you could do that. That's a cool command. Unfortunately, I get this: `output is : (null)`

Comment: Don't forget that I'm doing this on a simulator. Could that be my problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44264/discussion-between-usr55410-and-2intor)